# Taylor expansion of at a point different from $0$: should the variable be changed?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Find the Taylor expansion of $\arcsin x$ at point $1$.

Can we change variable to get the series at point $0$? If yes how,  and when do we  change again to get back to $1$?

#### More generally

Let's suppose we have a function that can be developed around a point different than $0$, is it necessary to create new function to be developed around $0$? Like, from  $\ln(x)$ around $2$, use $x= t +2$ where $t$ is something very small around $0$, so we study instead the function $\ln( t+2)$? I didn't get this process which our teacher used to demonstrate.

Comment: add title to Question.

Comment: Well, $\;\arcsin x\;$ is defined on $\;[-1\,,\,1]\;$ and that  doesn't leave much room to develop it *around* $\;x=1\;$ .

Comment: Let's suppose we have a function that can be developed around a point different than 0 , is it necessary to create new function to be developed around 0 like ln(x) around 2 and pose x= t +2 where t is smthing very small around 0 so we study instead the function ln( t+2) ? Ididn' t get this process which our teacher used to demonstrate

Comment: do you have a concrete function and a point different from zero?

Comment: I think so,  i guess taylor series is only feasible at point 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find a series expansion of $\ln $ around $x = 2.$  one way to do this is by a change of variable like $x = 2 + h.$  so

$$\ln x = \ln (2 + h) = \ln 2 + \ln (1 + h/2) = \ln 2 + (h/2) - \frac{1}{2}(h/2)^2 + \cdots $$ valid for $-2 < h \le 2.$

Comment: That's what i was trying to confirm ,  Thank you very much

Comment: @SeriusBlack, you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes changing the variable helps:  for example, if we know 
$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
then to expand around $x=2$, write $x=2+t$ and observe that $e^{2+t}=e^2 e^t$. Use the formula above to get 
$$
e^x = e^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}
$$
and change back to 
$$
e^x =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty  e^2 \frac{(x-2)^n}{n!}
$$

But it's not a universal recipe. The success depends on whether after the substitution we get a reasonable function in terms of $t$.

Also, in your example with $\arcsin x$ the problem is that it does not even have the first derivative at $x=1$, so Taylor expansion at that point does not exist.